# break apart formatted date into individual month/day/year hour/minute/second in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date in the following format

```
November 18, 2009, 3:00PM
```

How can i break that up so that i can store each value as its own variable?

such as...

```
$month //November
$day //18
$year //2009
$hour //03
$minute //00
$ampm //PM
```

Comment: Don't edit your solution into your question. Post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "November 18, 2009, 3:00PM";
list($month,$day,$year,$time) = preg_split('/[ ,]/',$str,false,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)([AP]M)/',$time,$timeparts);
list($time,$hour,$minute,$ampm) = $timeparts;

echo "\$month  $month\n";
echo "\$day    $day\n";
echo "\$year   $year\n";
echo "\$hour   $hour\n";
echo "\$minute $minute\n";
echo "\$ampm   $ampm\n";
```

Output

```
$month  November
$day    18
$year   2009
$hour   3
$minute 00
$ampm   PM
```

Comment: this was the easiest option of all. You win! Thanks for the help and time everyone.

Comment: Yes, it was the closest match to what you seemed to want, but the other suggestions have credit for being, more flexible, safer and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Use the 'date_parse' (http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) function. It returns an array with the parsed items:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2006
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 12
    [hour] => 10
    [minute] => 0
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 0.5
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array()
    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array()
    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Comment: how would i handle the ampm part?

Comment: date_parse will return the hour on a 24h basis.

Comment: The AM / PM part can be parsed with the 'date_parse_from_format'-function. It accepts a format used by all the date functions. These formats can contain AM/PM specification. See the details here: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

Comment: actually that function doesnt seem to work on my version of php...weird

Comment: Or you can extract the AM/PM information separately with the A or a formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your date into a timestamp, then with the timestamp you can easily get your parts. An other way is using a regular expression.

Comment: -1 for regex for dates. there are so many better php ways to do this.

Comment: True, I'm only mentioning options. I mentioned the regex as last, thereby I kinda mean it's not my favorite option. I prefer the datefunction ofcourse.

Comment: with specific requirements regex is a good option. albeit not _the_ best option.

Comment: It's more because of the sort-of lazyness for not using Google for these situations.. This is widely discussed and there are many, many examples available...

Answer (score 1):

**More complex solution.**
If your dates may be in the different standards you can use date() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) + strtotime() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which parse string and returns the unix timestamp.

For example, if you want to get a year from your date string you could write next code:

```
$date = 'November 18, 2009, 3:00PM';

$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
```

Or, if you want to know how much days in the month in date you get, you could write such code:

```
$date = 'November 18, 2009, 3:00PM';

$num_of_days = date('t', strtotime($date));
```

't' returns the number of days in the given month.