# PHP Reduce days, hours and minutes from a datetime

Tags: php, datetime

Need to reduce no of days, hours and minutes from a datetime using php.

Datetime is of the format **Y-m-d H:i:s**

eg: Suppose datetime is **2013-03-20 14:20:00**. How to reduce **2 days** , **3 hours** and **10 minutes** from this such that it results in **2013-03-18 11:10:00**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [break apart formatted date into individual month/day/year hour/minute/second in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769467/break-apart-formatted-date-into-individual-month-day-year-hour-minute-second-in)

Comment: @meagar: What if the I datetime is 2013-03-20 05:00:00 and reduce 1 day 8hours and 30 min from this. Here it should give 2013-03-18 21:30:00. I think splitting it is not right

Comment: you can use the `strtotime` for your need. Check the following Q & A you will find your answer in them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435835/decrease-5-days-from-a-date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768846/need-to-subtract-12-hours-and-30-minutes-from-the-date-sat-30-apr-2011-050000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)   object :

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-03-20 14:20:00');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P2DT3H10M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$date =  new DateTime("2013-03-20 14:20:00");
$dateIncremented = $date->sub(date_interval_create_from_date_string('2 days 3 hours 10 minutes'));
$finalDate = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $finalDate;
?>
```

Allirght. An Alias. But Readable format

Answer (score 1):

You must explore [DateTime::sub](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), and about [DateInterval format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

```
echo \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-03-20 14:20:00')
    ->sub(new \DateInterval('P2DT3H10M'))
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2013-03-18 11:10:00
```